# Doubts about IUPAC nomenclature of 4-ethyl-1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, structural-formula

Why is 4-ethyl-1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene (structure is in the attached picture) called so ?

Shouldn't it be called as 1-ethyl-4-fluoro-3-nitrobenzene since the *precedence of ethyl is greater than halogens*?

[image: 4-ethyl-1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene]

Answer (score 8):

The current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule f takes precedence over Rule g. Also note that all prefixes (i.e. ethyl, fluoro, and nitro) are considered together; i.e., there isn’t any order of functional group priorities at this point.

Furthermore,

> **P-14.3.5** Lowest set of locants
>
> The lowest set of locants is defined as the set that, when compared term by term with
> other locant sets, each cited in order of increasing value, has the lowest term at the first
> point of difference; (…)

Therefore, the example is named as **4-ethyl-1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene** rather than 1-ethyl-4-fluoro-3-nitrobenzene since the locant set ‘1,2,4’ is lower than ‘1,3,4’.

[image: 4-ethyl-1-fluoro-2-nitrobenzene]

Comment: I see that the locant set of 1,2,4 is lower than 1,3,4 but the precedence of ethyl is greater than fluorine .. so shouldn't ethyl get the lowest number ?

Comment: @user126190 The prefixes (‘ethyl’, ‘fluoro’, and ‘nitro’) are ‘**all considered together** in a series of increasing numerical order’.

Comment: But this website [link](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/02/14/table-of-functional-group-priorities-for-nomenclature/) and many other websites too say alkanes are before halogens ..

Comment: @user126190 Your link is about the seniority of functional classes in functional class nomenclature, which is not related to your question. In your example, the functional class is already given; it is neither _alkane_ nor _alkyl halide_ – it is _benzene._

Comment: @Loong is correct. As far as numbering of locants is concerned, alkyls, alkoxys, halos, and nitros all has the **lowest** priority because they are substituent only functional groups.