# How to name the tautomers of hexane-2,4-dione correctly according to IUPAC rules?

Tags: nomenclature, reference-request, erratum

Today I was considering to answer the question "[Which tautomer of hexane-2,4-dione is more stable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/44219/4945)" I wanted to run a few calculations and while preparing a directory structure I wanted to make sure that I used correct and unique names for the compounds. I am citing the picture in the named question:

[image: scheme of tautomers]

I was going to derive the names of the structures from the parent compound hexane-2,4-dione. Hence I would have named compound **1** (*Z*)-2-hydroxyhex-2-en-4-one and **2** (*Z*)-4-hydroxyhex-3en-2-one.

When I recreated the above picture in ChemBioDraw and used it to autogenerate the name, the result for **1** was different: (*Z*)-5-hydroxyhex-4-en-3-one. See below.

[image: scheme of tautomers with generated names]

I am no expert on nomenclature and I do not have the blue book handy. Usually I rely on the names generated through software. Most of the times they are accurate enough to name a compound unambiguously and that is often what I am going for.
I understood from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/24772/4945), **P-14.3.5** Lowest set of locants, that I should use the 4,2,2 set over the 5,3,2.

Is my thinking correct and the auto-generated names are wrong, or is the software correct and my thinking is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You numbered all locants together in a series and you found the lowest set of locants according to Subsection P-14.3.5 of the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* since the locant set ‘2,2,4’ is lower than ‘3,4,5’.

> **P-14.3.5** Lowest set of locants
>
> The lowest set of locants is defined as the set that, when compared term by term with
>   other locant sets, each cited in order of increasing value, has the lowest term at the first
>   point of difference; (…)

This approach would be correct if all locants refer to detachable prefixes (like ‘2-hydroxy’). However, in the given compounds, the locants refer to prefixes (‘hydroxy’), endings (‘ene’), and suffixes (‘one’). The assignment of low locants to such different features is stipulated in Subsection P-14.4 as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (…)

Therefore, the resulting name is (4​*Z*)-5-hydroxyhex-4-en-3-one (not (2​*Z*)-2-hydroxyhex-2-en-4-one) since the locant ‘3-one’ for the principal characteristic groups is lower than ‘4-one’.

[image: (4​Z)-5-hydroxyhex-4-en-3-one]

Answer (score 1):

You will assign lowest locant to the group with highest priority. Here priority order is 
Keto>hydroxy>alkene. So use that numbering which gives lowest locant to keto group. So I think the names given by software are correct.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could back that up with the official sources, hence the reference request.

Comment: Ok. Sure. I will definitely try to provide a good reference. That's the logic I have learnt and it also matches with software.

Comment: One of the reference is 'Organic Chemistry' by John E. Mcmurry. There is an article in the book stepwise describing nomenclature of polyfunctional compounds. It also gives a priority order for common functional groups